# Updating state in a forEach loop in React is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to update a state each time I receive a promise, in a loop. But my state only shows the last promise.

I guess it's because, as the set state is asynchronous, it uses the Map available before the previous state updates.

How can I achieve that without using a `Promise.all?

```js
const [dataList, setDataList] = useRef(new Map())

  useEffect(() => {
    ids.forEach(id => {
      getData(id).then(data => {
        if (data) {
          setDataList(dataList.set(id, data))
        }
      })
    })
  }, [ids])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to how React works. It waits for all `setState` calls for a specific `state` and picks the last one to update the DOM.

If you wanna avoid this behavior, use an updater function that will always get the freshest `state`, even if the component didn't render since. Like so:

```js
ids.forEach((id) => {
  getData(id).then((data) => {
    if (data) {
      setDataList((dataList) => {
        let newDataList = new Map(dataList);
        newDataList.set(id, data);
        return newDataList;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it with async await this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ids.forEach(id => {
    async function fetchMyAPI() {
      const data = await getData(id);
      if (data) {
        setDataList(dataList.set(id, data))
      }
    }
    fetchMyAPI()
  })
}, [ids])
```